# Deploy flask on my local machine with no server

Tags: flask

I need to deploy a Flask app without using a web server. Is that possible to run my Flask application on my local machine and make the app accessible via the Internet without having to deploy the app on a server?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your site available in productive mode, you need a server. Flask's development server is suitable for development only. However, that doesn't mean you have to set up Apache or Nginx. Among the possible variants, gunicorn or waitress are also available, depending on the system available. These are easy to install using the Python package manager and are just as easy to start as Flask's own development server.
If you would like to use one of the larger servers and not install it directly, you can also try to install it via a docker container. However, this is a little more complicated.

Make sure that you start the server you are using with an IP address that can be reached by external devices. An example would be the address `0.0.0.0`.

You can find an overview of the available alternatives [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/deploying/).